# Erro ao consutar o Banco de dado pelo programa pgAdmin4;

Tags: postgresql

Boa tarde,
estou tendo problemas parecidos quando tento pesquisar no BD.
Digito:

```
SELECT * FROM profission(cod_prof,nome_prof,sexo_prof,cref_prof,titulo_prof) 
VALUES ('Fernando','masculino','0001','doutorado');
```

e tenho o resultado:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Fernando'"
>   LINE 1: ...ome_prof,sexo_prof,cref_prof,titulo_prof) values ('Policapo'...
>                                                                ^
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 186

Alguém poderia indicar qual seria o problema.
Agraço.

Comment: De acordo com a documentação esta não é uma construção sintaticamente válida para o comando SELECT. Não entendi o que deseja fazer. Se os dados estão no banco e você deseja recuperá-los não tem nenhum sentido a cláusula VALUES. Talvez a cláusula WHERE atenda a suas necessidades.

Comment: Entendi. Na realidade o que esta ocorrendo é que estou tentando fazer a pesquisa na base de dados. Obrigado

Comment: Veja se é isto:
SELECT * FROM profission 
WHERE nome_prof='Fernando' AND sexo_prof='masculino' AND cref_prof='0001' AND titulo_prof='doutorado';